# cannot convert html file to dompdf using phpword, PDF rendering library or library path has not been defined

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf, phpword

I dont know why my program cannot find the path in it

it keeps showing the

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception' with message 'PDF rendering library or library path has not been defined.' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTproject\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Writer\PDF.php:50 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTproject\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\IOFactory.php(44): PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\PDF->__construct(Object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord)) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTproject\123.php(42): PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter(Object(PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord), 'PDF') 
#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTproject\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Writer\PDF.php on line 50
```

and the first $t returns empty value

I set the path in testpdf.php below:

```
1 <?php
2 
3 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
4 // Creating the new document...
5 $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
6 
7 /* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */
8 
9 // Adding an empty Section to the document...
10$section = $phpWord->addSection();
11// Adding Text element with font customized using named font style...
12$fontStyleName = 'oneUserDefinedStyle';
13$phpWord->addFontStyle(
14        $fontStyleName, array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10, 'color' => '1B2232', 'bold' => true)
15);
16$section->addText(
17        '"The greatest accomplishment is not in never falling, '
18        . 'but in rising again after you fall." '
19        . '(Vince Lombardi)', $fontStyleName
20);
21
22// Adding Text element with font customized using explicitly created font style object...
23$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
24$fontStyle->setBold(true);
25$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
26$fontStyle->setSize(13);
27$myTextElement = $section->addText('"Believe you can and you\'re halfway there." (Theodor Roosevelt)');
28$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);
29
30// Saving the document as HTML file...
31$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
32$objWriter->save('helloWorld.html');
33
34$domPdfPath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTproject\vendor\dompdf\dompdf';
35$t = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
36echo $t . '   first<br>';
37
38$t = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');
39echo $t . '   second<br>';
40
41$temp = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('helloWorld.docx');
42$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($temp, 'PDF');
43$xmlWriter->save('helloWorld.pdf');
44?>
```

I changed the phpword.ini.dist to phpword.ini  and set the absolute path  in 
'pdfRendererPath       = "C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTproject\vendor\dompdf\dompdf"'

When I changed the path into 'vendor/dompdf/dompdf', it shows

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception' with
message 'Unable to load PDF Rendering library'
```

BTW, is anything in `\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Writer\PDF` useful? I haven't touched anything in it yet

Comment: Change your $domPdfPath to use single quotes (apostrophes)

Comment: i tried it, but it doesn't work...